# Spring Cloud Stream - Output Messages from EventListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, event-driven

I'm trying to utilize the `@DomainEvents` mechanism provided by Spring Data to publish Events with Spring Cloud Stream (Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 and Finchley.M5). I have a two-part question.

1. Why does `SendTo` not work on `EventListeners`?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

The `DomainEvent` is being created and sent to the `EventListener` without issues. The problem is that the `SendTo` mechanism didn't seem to be working. The first method below would trigger, but not forward the message. Manually building the `Message` and sending it as shown in the second method works correctly.

```
@Async
@TransactionalEventListener
@SendTo(Sink.Output)
StreamedEvent handleEventWithSendTo(MyEvent event) {
    // handle and create event
}

@TransactionalEventListener
void handleEvent(MyEvent event) {
    // handle and create event
    sink.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).build())
}
```

The call-out in the [Spring Cloud Stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_streamlistener_for_automatic_content_type_handling) docs shows using `SendTo` on a `StreamListener`, which is not quite the same thing as an `EventListener`, but I thought it may work.

For the second part, using `DomainEvents` requires the service code persisting the `Entity` to know about the event (to either call `registerEvent` directly or some method on the `Entity` which represents the event). I was curious if using the Spring Data callback hooks (e.g. `PreUpdate`, `PostUpdate`) would be better. Or if there was a better way all together.

Comment: >`but I thought it may work.` No; the `@SendTo` logic for a `@StreamListener` is specifically handled by the listener annotation processor.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the confirmation.